# What is the most efficient system for System Users with Plesk Webspaces

Tags: web, hosting, plesk

I am attempting to start a web hosting business, and I am using the Plesk API to create the subscription, but I am wondering what the optimal method to creating system users is. Do I just use random strings for the username and password? Do I make the usernames site1, site2, site3, etc.[image]

Answer (score 0):

System username is a user that can connect to the server via SSH, upload files via FTP. This user doesn't have access to Plesk GUI. There are several limitations for system users:
https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213395409

Password depends on [security settings](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/administrator-guide/plesk-administration/securing-plesk/setting-up-the-password-strength-policy.71081/). 
Also password must not contain a systmem username. It's up to you to to decide what username and password should be random strings or something meaningful.